# Rail3 - Browser is asking for a username & password when not signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

recently my Rails 3 app started asking for a username and password via a browser prompt when loading the home page and not signed in...

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :all, :cache => true %>
```

I was able to determine that it's the line above causing the issue. If I remove that it doesn't happen.

Ideas? Have you seen this before ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Woops! Turns out I had an ajax call for signed in users in the application.js...

bad bad me